# Matching regular expression

Tags: php, regex, curl, preg-match

I am trying to get the data from all the div's with price in them in the following section of code:

```
<section data-v-7630ac7c="" view-more-component="">
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" table-component="" data-v-7630ac7c="">
<header data-v-5c5571e4="">
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" price="" right-align="">Price</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" quantity="" right-align="">Quantity</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" date="">Time</div></header> <section data-v-5c5571e4="">
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" price="" right-align="" style="color: rgb(142, 201, 25);">8611.00</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" quantity="" right-align="">1.00000000</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" date="">13:27:17</div></section><section data-v-5c5571e4="">
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" price="" right-align="" style="color: rgb(142, 201, 25);">8612.30</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" quantity="" right-align="">1.00000000</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" date="">13:03:12</div></section><section data-v-5c5571e4="">
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" price="" right-align="" style="color: rgb(255, 42, 104);">8517.70</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" quantity="" right-align="">0.04983464</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" date="">12:51:24</div></section><section data-v-5c5571e4="">
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" price="" right-align="" style="color: rgb(142, 201, 25);">8608.70</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" quantity="" right-align="">0.59195657</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" date="">12:32:26</div></section><section data-v-5c5571e4="">
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" price="" right-align="" style="color: rgb(255, 42, 104);">8521.70</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" quantity="" right-align="">0.02990000</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" date="">11:29:57</div></section><section data-v-5c5571e4="">
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" price="" right-align="" style="color: rgb(142, 201, 25);">8545.20</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" quantity="" right-align="">0.26101049</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" date="">01:20:35</div></section><section data-v-5c5571e4="">
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" price="" right-align="" style="color: rgb(255, 42, 104);">8462.30</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" quantity="" right-align="">0.00674370</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" date="">23:49:47</div></section><section data-v-5c5571e4="">
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" price="" right-align="" style="color: rgb(142, 201, 25);">8539.30</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" quantity="" right-align="">0.05799985</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" date="">23:00:53</div></section><section data-v-5c5571e4="">
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" price="" right-align="" style="color: rgb(255, 42, 104);">8446.00</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" quantity="" right-align="">0.02345439</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" date="">22:30:43</div></section><section data-v-5c5571e4="">
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" price="" right-align="" style="color: rgb(255, 42, 104);">8540.00</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" quantity="" right-align="">0.25500001</div> 
<div data-v-5c5571e4="" date="">21:55:28</div></section></div> 
<section data-v-7630ac7c="" id="my-trades"><div data-v-75ce2ffa="" data-v-7630ac7c="" button-component="" class="viewmore fullbutton">
<button data-v-75ce2ffa=""></button> 
<!----> <span data-v-75ce2ffa="" text="">View More</span> <!----></div> <!----></section> <!----> <!----></section> <!---->
```

The regular expression i am using is

```
<div (..................) price="" (.*)">(.*)<\/div>
```

But I keep getting NULL. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual _code_ that you're using?

Comment: What value are you trying to get? Please add your PHP. If the HTML extends to two lines the `.` won't cover that (or possibly unless you used modifier). A parser would be much easier to work with.

Comment: HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Regex is perfectly fine for extracting such data, when you're versed enough. `<div[^>]+price=\"\"[^>]+>([\d.]+)<`. Else a DOM traversal frontend is advisable. And with autogenerated output such as that, chances are a proper API exists.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3577641)

Comment: I have never used the parser its why I went with curl and preg match, if you guys know of a better method, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Although parsing html with regex is strongly discouraged your posted html code only contains div tags without nesting so you can apply this simple regex and do your job of getting all prices from div tags:

```
<div.*?price.*?>(\d+\.\d+)<\/div>
```

But keep this as a temporary fix and if you have to use it in long run then go for an html parser.

Demo,

https://regex101.com/r/JBwRM5/1

Answer (score 0):

I tried both they didnt work here is the whole code i am using

```
<?
$curl = curl_init();
$SearchString = "BTCCAD";
$url = "https://einstein.exchange/trade?mode=advanced&instrument=$SearchString";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
preg_match_all('<div[^>]+price=\"\"[^>]+>([\d.]+)<',$result,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Comment: So i tried the parser but most of the data in the page is created through JS and so the parser doesnt load it.